# Should I respond with a 400 error if a form submit contains validation errors?

Tags: html, forms, http, web, http-status-codes

In a classic form-based webapp, if a user submits a HTML form that contains validation errors, assuming no JavaScript, what's the correct thing to do?

1. Respond with the HTTP 200 + the page content (including error info for the user)
2. Respond with the HTTP 400 + the page content (including error info for the user)

Does it matter?

Comment: It would be odd to throw an HTTP error code for something that is not a protocol problem.  If the validation is wrong, that doesn't fall under 400s description of *The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.* (validation shouldn't even have been able to run, the server didn't understand the request).

Comment: That's RFC2616 which is now obsoleted by RFC7230-RFC7235. RFC7231 provides a more border definition which could cover validation errors. WebDAV provides a status code 422 which seems a better fit. So if it was an API, I would have sent 422. For a website consumed by people, 200 might be appropriate if you don't want the error message to be rendered in a different 'user-friendly' way by the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app is talking to human beings, not other machines.  Therefore you should do the right thing and handle exceptions in a user-friendly manner.

Your user doesn't care about HTTP return codes, and so it should not even be a consideration for you either.  You are confusing business-logic problems with HTTP protocol problems.

Infact, by throwing a 400 error at a web-browser, you are only likely to encounter the web browser throwing up an ugly message to the user.

If you were coding a REST api, then the answer would be different.  But you're not.

Answer (score 2):

1) would be the correct approach because you want to display a page of content to the user that highlights the invalid input values.

The trouble with 2) is that some browsers may display their own 'friendly' error page that is designed to help users understand 4xx errors. Here's some information about when IE displays 'friendly' error pages:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, if it is a web app for human consumption, a 200 with a some useful error message will work. Making web sites for humans is easier in that sense because they can read and understand the content and do not have to depend on the status code for interact with the applications.

On the other hand, If you thinking of a REST API more appropriate would be to throw a 4xx error because it is a client side error. In that case, you have several options.

According [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.1), a 400 means

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
> syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
> modifications.

This doesn't seem to be appropriate as it's not due to malformed syntax.

However, [RFC2616 is now obsoleted by RFC7230-7235](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead). The new [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) defines the meaning of 400 in a more broader way.

> Client Error 4xx The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates
> that the client seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD
> request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an
> explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or
> permanent condition.
>
> 400 Bad Request
>
> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing)

So this seems acceptable even though still generic. Another option would be to use [422 status code](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) defined by [RFC4918 (WebDAV)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2).

> 422 Unprocessable Entity The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code
> means the server understands the content type of the request entity
> (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate),
> and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad
> Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the
> contained instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur
> if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically
> correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.